# Exclude Agent from Azure Devops using YML

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to determine if there's a way to exclude a specific agent using an azure devops yml file. I know I can specify that it uses a specific agent like this

```
pool:
  name: MyPool
  demands:
  - agent.os -equals Darwin
```

But I'm pretty much looking for the inverse, is there a way to effectively do something like this:

```
  - agent.os -not-equals Darwin
```

So as to say use anything except the agent Darwin. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Daniel Mann.

In Azure Devops, the demands parameters only supports the `equals` and `exists` operations.

> Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Here is a workaround to achieve this:

You could add the `User-defined capabilities` for each agent in `Agent Pools -> Each Agent -> Capabilities`.

Example:

[image]

You can add a custom capability to distinguish whether it is Darwin.

Then you could use exists or equals in Yaml file.

For example:

```
pool:
  name: MyPool
  demands:
  - Darwin -equals NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manually-entered-demands):

> Checking for the existence of a capability (exists) and checking for a specific string in a capability (equals) are the only two supported operations for demands.